# Unable to append object to nested list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "modulename": "module1",
    "functions": [
      {
        "functionname": "get",
        "function": "function1"
      },
      {
        "functionname": "delete",
        "function": "function2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code looks like this:

```
modules = []

for functionname in function_dictionary:

    modulename = function_dictionary[function][1]
    func = function_dictionary[function][0]


    module_func = {"modulename" : modulename, "functions" : [{"functionname" : functionname, "function" : func}]}

    found = False
    for module in modules:
        if module["modulename"] == modulename:
            module["modulename"]["functions"].append({"functionname" : functionname, "function" : func}) #error here
            found = True
            break

    if not found:
        modules.append(module_func)
```

However I keep getting the `string indices must be integers, not str` error.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this.

I read it as "append the object `{"functionname" : function, "function" : func}` to the list located at `module["modulename"]["functions"]`

Any advice is apprciated!

Comment: Replace `module["modulename"]["functions"].append` with `module["functions"].append` ; `module["modulename"]` is a string, indeed

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, was a typo on my part:

```
module["modulename"]["functions"].append({"functionname" : functionname, "function" : func}) #error here
```

Should have been:

```
module["functions"].append({"functionname" : function, "function" : func})
```

I was misreading my own object and though that the `functions` list was nested inside `modulename` when in fact they were at the same level.